# Which software should I add to Ubuntu Server 13.04 to host media files and stream them to my WD TV Live

Tags: server, streaming

I am new to Ubuntu Server and would like to use it to host media files and download new media files and stream them to my [Western Digital TV Live Media Player](http://www.amazon.ca/WD-Live-Streaming-Media-Player/dp/B005PLHF4S/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1368764702&sr=1-1&keywords=wd+tv+live).

While installing Ubuntu Server 13.04, I get to choose which software to install with it. Which one should I choose (if any)?[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of those. You're looking for a DLNA server, something like Twonky, Plex, Serviio etc.

Comment: It would be more helpful you could include download and/or configuration instructions with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use Serviio.  I download the .tar.gz,  unzip it to ~/.serviio  and then start the ./serviio.sh  and then  ./serviio-console.sh   and after starting the latter, I will get a little status icon in my task bar  (next to the clock) that lets me manage the service.  It works great.